# Merge StateFlows

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I have a problem that I can't get around by myself.
In my viewModel I have two StateFlows that are merged into one Flow.
Just like `val mergedState = merge(state1, state2)`.
Now when I update state1 the value of mergedState also changes to the value of state1.
But when I try to update state2 then the value of mergedState won't change.

For better demonstration I wrote a simple example:

Here is the viewModel

```
class FlowViewModel : ViewModel() {

    private val state1 = MutableStateFlow(0)
    private val state2 = MutableStateFlow(0)

    val mergedState = merge(state1, state2)

    fun updateState1(value: Int) {
        state1.value = value
    }

    fun updateState2(value: Int) {
        state2.value = value
    }
}
```

And here is the code to test it

```
class ExampleUnitTest {

    private lateinit var flowViewModel: FlowViewModel

    @Before
    fun setUp() {
        Dispatchers.setMain(UnconfinedTestDispatcher())
        flowViewModel = FlowViewModel()
    }

    @After
    fun tearDown() {
        Dispatchers.resetMain()
    }

    @Test
    fun `test merged flow`() = runTest {
        assertThat(flowViewModel.mergedState.first()).isEqualTo(0)

        flowViewModel.updateState1(1)
        assertThat(flowViewModel.mergedState.first()).isEqualTo(1) //works as expected

        flowViewModel.updateState2(2)
        assertThat(flowViewModel.mergedState.first()).isEqualTo(2) //the value is still 1
    }
}
```

I also doesn't matter which state I update first.
It looks like that only updating state1 will also update the mergedState.

I'm pretty sure that I overlook something here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that flows are COLD and they do not keep the state.

Your `merge(state1, state2)` will always emit current `state1` then `state2` when you start collecting it, only after that it will start "relaying" updates.

Your assertions:

```
assertThat(flowViewModel.mergedState.first()).isEqualTo(1)
```

Begin and finish collecting your merged state after first value which will always be the current state of `state1`.

You can either: make your `mergedState` a state flow:

```
val mergedState = merge(state1, state2).stateIn(viewModelScope, SharingStarted.Eagerly, state1.value)
```

Or update your test to keep collecting the `mergedState` instead of restarting it 3 times over.

Comment: Yes of course I know there was something I didn't realise properly before reviewing this. Thank you very much.